# Requirements to drive to Mexico from USA

Tags: usa, borders, mexico

I have read this (but talks only about rental cars): 
[What do I need if I want to travel from USA to Mexico with a rental car?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14085/what-do-i-need-if-i-want-to-travel-from-usa-to-mexico-with-a-rental-car)

And I have read this (does not talk about visitors(to the US)) : 
http://guadalajara.usconsulate.gov/general_information/frequently-asked-questions/what-are-the-requirements-for-taking-my-car-to-mexico.html

I have a buddy with me who has a Bangladesh passport. Has a B1/B2 visa and an I94 card. I  (have a US license and a US passport) and he wish to drive to Mexico. What are the requirements for us to do so ? I don't want to rent a car but drive my truck (Ford F-250). Do I need to buy extra Vehicle Insurance other than the comprehensive one I got right now ? We will spend barely 48 hours in the Mexican side.

Comment: What part of Mexico? The frontera / Baja does not require a vehicle permit but mainland does. Mexico Car Permits can now be processed online at (but you of course still need the sticker for your windsheild) ... https://www.banjercito.com.mx/registroVehiculos/ ... Their is also other information on that link.

Comment: The requirements also change if your buddy has a valid US Visa. http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/servicios-a-extranjeros/108

Comment: Sorry my questions are broken up into several comments. The internet is not working well for me today. If you answer these Qs I can confirm an answer with the customer service at the agency I work with.

Comment: All we wanted to do over a weekend (beginning Friday night) was to visit a new country, experience the local culture, see some places of natural beauty, eat some Mexican food and have some beer. I will be driving in from Texas so Baja is too far. Now that I google for specific places, looks like Gudalajara and Mexico city are both hundreds of miles inland. Matamoros seems close enough but not too much to do. I guess I am in a fix now

Comment: My internet connection is still causing problems, but was able to determine that Texas does not have an Enhanced Driver's License. So you will need a passport, your buddy will need a US visa that allows him multiple entries into the US; as both of you need to get back into the US. If you have those then there will be some fees as pointed out by Flimsy; you need two tourists cards, about $20 each, Mexican Liability insurance about $20 a day, and make a deposit for the Vehicle, (which can be done on a credit card), you get the deposit back when you return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only address the issue of your U.S. vehicle.  I have no experience with Bangladesh passports or Mexican visa requirements for Bangladesh citizens.

You are not legally required to buy insurance in Mexico, but you would be crazy not to.  If you are in an accident without insurance in Mexico, you stand to have your car impounded, and spend at least a night in jail.

See [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4864/444) for suggestions on where to buy Mexican car insurance.

Aside from that, to actually enter the country with your vehicle, you will need:

- Proof that you are the owner of the vehicle.  The original title, or registration receipt will suffice.
- Your drivers' license
- Your passport
- 2 photocopies of each (If you arrive without photocopies, you can have copies made there, usually for a small fee, or a tip)

When you cross the border, you will need to find the nearest Customs (Aduana) office. It's usually very near the border crossing, but not always immediately obvious.  There should be signs (usually in English, too), pointing to Vehicle or Car Permits.

Once there, expect to spend some time in line.  Although how much time varies greatly depending on which border crossing you use, and the time of day.  If you can cross early in the morning, or on a Sunday, you may be the only one in line.  If you cross during a busy time, you may be in line 2-3 hours.

You will be required to present your passport, and fill out a small permit card (assuming you are entering as a tourist), and return to the window where the clerk will give you (typically) 180 days, and hand the permit back to you.

Then you will go to the [Banjercito](http://www.banjercito.com.mx/) window where you will pay your fees.  There is a visa fee, a vehicle importation fee, and the big thing, a temporary vehicle importation deposit, which varies depending on the model year of your vehicle.  You can pay these fees in cash or with a credit card.

You will then receive a vehicle permit to stick in your windshield.

At this point, you are free to enter the country (beyond the "free trade zone").

When you leave the country with your vehicle, be sure to return to the Customs office wherever you are leaving, and turn in your vehicle permit to receive the refund on your deposit.